# Excel: Populate column C with differences between A and B

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns in 2 worksheets (WS1 & WS2) containing STRING value columns: A and B.
I want to populate a third column "C" in a third worksheet (WS3) with the differences.

Put simply, I want to populate column WS3:C with item names that are in WS1:A but not in WS2:B.

Comment: Much more easily with VBA - is that something you'd be happy to use?

Comment: Yes I'm quite familiar with VB (I write VB.NET ASP)

Comment: I misunderstood initially, I don't think you'd need VBA here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually do quite simply:

[image]

The formula in column C is

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10,A1),"",A1)
```

---

Here is a VBA alternative:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DisplayUnique()
    Dim output As Range, r As Range
    Dim dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set output = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1")

    For Each r In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B10").Find(r.Value, , , xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            If Not dict.exists(r.Value) Then dict.Add r.Value, r.Value
        End If
    Next r

    output.Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
End Sub
```

Comment: I've had to make a change to the workbook, meaning these columns are now on separate worksheets - can this formula be modified or is VBS now a better option?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft Just specify the worksheet before each range, like `'Sheet'1!A1` or `'Sheet2'!$B$1:$B$10`

Comment: Thank you - This does basically do the job, however it leaves Column C very broken-up (lots of white space)

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft, I've added a VBA solution which will line them up nicely for you

Comment: Awesomeness - Thank you!